# How to read Exchange calendar properties in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, exchange-server, mapi, ekeventkit

I am building an iOS app which adds EKEvent items to a calendar which is synced with an Exchange server. This Exchange server adds custom properties to the event items.

Is there any possibility to read the custom properties of the Exchange items in the iOS app?

Answer (score 0):

You can read custom properties from an item in an Exchange mailbox using EWS or RPC.